# Is it possible to make Font Awesome icons larger than 'fa-5x'?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using this HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
          <div class="huge">
            <?=db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE customer = '" . $_SESSION['customer'] . "' AND EntryDate BETWEEN '" . date('d-M-y', strtotime('Monday this week')) . "' AND '" . date('d-M-y', strtotime('Friday this week')) . "'");?>
          </div>
            <div>orders this week</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="view/orders">
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
          <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which creates:

[image]

Is it possible to make the icon larger than `fa-5x`? There is a lot of white space beneath it that I would like it to take up.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Font awesome is just a font so you can use the font size attribute in your CSS to change the size of the icon.

So you can just add a class to the icon like this:

```
.big-icon {
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Alternatively you can edit the source and create your own incrementations

**FontAwesome 5**

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/5.15.4/less/_larger.less

```less
// Icon Sizes
// -------------------------

.larger(@factor) when (@factor > 0) {
  .larger((@factor - 1));

  .@{fa-css-prefix}-@{factor}x {
    font-size: (@factor * 1em);
  }
}

/* makes the font 33% larger relative to the icon container */
.@{fa-css-prefix}-lg {
  font-size: (4em / 3);
  line-height: (3em / 4);
  vertical-align: -.0667em;
}

.@{fa-css-prefix}-xs {
  font-size: .75em;
}

.@{fa-css-prefix}-sm {
  font-size: .875em;
}

// Change the number below to create your own incrementations
// This currently creates classes .fa-1x - .fa-10x
.larger(10);
```

**FontAwesome 4**

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/v4.7.0/less/larger.less

```less
// Icon Sizes
// -------------------------

/* makes the font 33% larger relative to the icon container */
.@{fa-css-prefix}-lg {
    font-size: (4em / 3);
    line-height: (3em / 4);
    vertical-align: -15%;
}

.@{fa-css-prefix}-2x { font-size: 2em; }
.@{fa-css-prefix}-3x { font-size: 3em; }
.@{fa-css-prefix}-4x { font-size: 4em; }
.@{fa-css-prefix}-5x { font-size: 5em; }

// Your custom sizes
.@{fa-css-prefix}-6x { font-size: 6em; }
.@{fa-css-prefix}-7x { font-size: 7em; }
.@{fa-css-prefix}-8x { font-size: 8em; }
```

Answer (score 13):

You can redefine/overwrite the default **font-awesome** sizes and also add you own sizes

```
.fa-1x{
    font-size:0.8em;
}
.fa-2x{
    font-size:1em;
}
.fa-3x{
    font-size:1.2em;
}
.fa-4x{
    font-size:1.4em;
}
.fa-5x{
    font-size:1.6em;
}
.fa-mycustomx{
    font-size:3.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Just add the font awesome class like this:

   ```
   class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-3x"
   ```

   (You can increase the size as per 5x, 7x, 9x..)
2. You can also add custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Easy — just use Font Awesome 5's default `fa-[size]x` classes. You can scale icons up to 10x of the parent element's `font-size` [Read the docs about icon sizing.](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons)

**Examples:**

```
<span class="fas fa-info-circle fa-6x"></span>
<span class="fas fa-info-circle fa-7x"></span>
<span class="fas fa-info-circle fa-8x"></span>
<span class="fas fa-info-circle fa-9x"></span>
<span class="fas fa-info-circle fa-10x"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome use SVG icons. So, you can resize it for your requirment.

just use CSS class for that,

```
    .large-icon{
       font-size:10em;
       //or
      font-size:200%;
      //or
      font-size:50px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a scale transformation, with CSS like so:

```
.larger-icon {
 transform:scale(2);
}
```