# Font-awesome ultra bold with css

Tags: css, fonts

I need font awesome much thicker. Trying to increase only height for default icons. Something like that as in picture for icon

`<i class="fa fa-exchange" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

[image]

I already try all bold property's and font awesome classes like `fa-4x or fa-5x` these are not suitable for me. And height property of css not work.

**How to increase height of font awesome icon?**

```
.my-link i{
   color:red;   
   height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make Font Awesome icons larger than 'fa-5x'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719319/is-it-possible-to-make-font-awesome-icons-larger-than-fa-5x)

Comment: Does adding a class that sets the font-size not work well enough? And note the picture you show *cannot* be produced from the font awesome icon unless you somehow start messing around with the relative placement of vertices inside the outline, with CSS absolutely can't do, so I assume you drew this yourself: just take that drawing, make it an image, then use that image in your own css. You don't have to use font awesome for everything, mix and match based on your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try ccs property:

```
transform: scale(1, 7);
```

```css
.fa { transform: scale(1,7); }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<i class="fa fa-exchange fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css for make bold.it's work on chrome

```
.my-link i{
-webkit-text-stroke: 4px;
}
```